# Java components being hidden in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

I have two `JPanels`, each with a bunch of `JButtons` in them. The `JPanel` containing the other two has a `BoxLayout` and the two other `JPanels` are `FlowLayout`. The problem is when the window is resized to make the buttons wrap, the buttons in the first and second panel (`p0`,`p2`) are covered up by the edge of their corresponding panels. Any ideas?

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.Scrollable;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel p0 = new JPanel();
        p0.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        p0.setBorder(new TitledBorder("p0"));
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        p1.setBorder(new TitledBorder("p1"));
        CustomPanel panel = new CustomPanel();
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(panel);
        panel.add(p0);
        panel.add(p1);
        frame.add(sp);
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        p0.add(new JButton("Hello World!"));
        p0.add(new JButton("Hello World!"));
        p0.add(new JButton("Hello World!"));
        p0.add(new JButton("Hello World!"));
        p0.add(new JButton("Hello World!"));
        p0.add(new JButton("Hello World!"));
        p0.add(new JButton("Hello World!"));
        p0.add(new JButton("Hello World!"));
        p1.add(new JButton("Hello World!"));
        p1.add(new JButton("Hello World!"));
        p1.add(new JButton("Hello World!"));
        p1.add(new JButton("Hello World!"));
        p1.add(new JButton("Hello World!"));
        p1.add(new JButton("Hello World!"));
        p1.add(new JButton("Hello World!"));
        p1.add(new JButton("Hello World!"));
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}

class CustomPanel extends JPanel implements Scrollable {

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FlowLayout does not recalculate the preferred size when components wrap.

Instead you can use the [Wrap Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/).

All you need to change is:

```
//p0.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
p0.setLayout(new WrapLayout());
```